# Find the spanning tree of a graph with the fewest vertices of odd degree

Tags: algorithm, tree, graph-theory

I have a graph, and I want to get the spanning tree with the fewest spanning tree odd-degree vertices ( counting only edges in the spanning tree ) among all spanning trees in the graph. Of course, an approximate solution is also possible (after all, the time complexity of finding all spanning trees is too high)

I tried to read the paper on finding all spanning trees in a graph, but the time complexity is too high.

Comment: If it exists, a Hamiltonian Path is obviously the optimal answer. But finding whether one exists is NP complete. Therefore there isn't a very good known algorithm.

Comment: The number of odd-degree vertices can be kept as small as possible, not necessarily the least. Can the greedy algorithm be implemented?

Comment: A spanning tree contains all the vertices in a graph.  So, every spanning tree contains the same number of odd degree vertices.

Comment: @ravenspoint I think the OP wants the MST with the fewest vertices of odd degree only considering edges of the MST.

Comment: @Dave That makes a lot more sense.

Comment: Is this problem similar to finding multiple Hamiltonian paths in a graph such that the number of paths is as small as possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @btilly notes, finding a Hamiltonian path in a cubic graph (an NP-hard problem) is equivalent to finding a spanning tree with only two vertices of odd degree, so this problem is hard in general.

You could try this local search method: starting from an arbitrary initial spanning tree, repeatedly choose a random edge not in the current spanning tree, add it to the tree, examine the resulting fundamental cycle, and delete the edge with the most endpoints of odd degree (leaving another spanning tree).

---

The graph that you're interested in is the fat-tree graph with k = 20. It's a bipartite graph with k²/4 + k²/2 = 300 nodes on one side (core and edge) and k²/2 = 200 nodes on the other (aggregation). We can show that every spanning tree has at least 102 nodes of odd degree. More generally,

**Theorem:** for every m ≥ n, for every bipartite graph G with m nodes on the left side and n nodes on the right, every spanning tree T of G has at least 2⌈(m − n + 1)/2⌉ vertices of odd degree (in T).

**Proof:** The tree T has exactly m + n − 1 edges, each connecting a left node and a right node. Every node in T has degree at least one. Accordingly, letting d be the number of left nodes of odd degree (in T), we derive an inequality

> d + 2(m − d) ≤ m + n − 1

since each node of odd degree has at least one incident edge, and each node of even degree has at least two incident edges. Do some algebra:

> m − d ≤ n − 1
> d ≥ m − n + 1.

We also know by the Handshaking Lemma that the total number of nodes of odd degree is even. Combining these facts yields the conclusion.

Comment: Can you be more careful, after deleting the edge of the spanning tree, it will no longer be a spanning tree, how to choose to insert new edges later?

Comment: I try to use the prim algorithm to add edges to odd-degree nodes first, so that the number of odd-degree vertices in the current spanning tree will not increase, but this effect does not seem to be very good.

Comment: I used your method to test in Fattree-20 topo, and reduced the odd-degree vertices of the spanning tree from 114 to 102

Comment: https://github.com/1101293857/model/blob/master/fat-tree.py  This code can generate fat-tree topo